# In Flutter how to combine two map'ed variables

Tags: flutter, array-merge, datacolumn

I am new to Flutter. I am sending two separate strings from Json to create a table in Flutter:

String one contains Column Titles with ~ separator

```
"column_titles": "Col Title 1~ColTitle-2~Title3~Column Title 4"
```

And the other string stores if the value is Numeric or Alpha (can be other formats but for simplicity A or N for the time being)

```
"column_types": "A~N~N~N"
```

I am converting the above into separate lists as follows:

```
var columnTypes = widget.columnTypes
    .split('~')
    .map((String text) => text)
    .toList();

var columnTitles = widget.titles
    .split('~')
    .map((String text) => DataColumn(
        label: Text(text), numeric: true)) // decide true or false based on columnTypes
    .toList();
```

Based on the value of `text` in `columnTypes` I need to insert true or false for `numeric` parameter of `DataColumn` in `columnTitles`

I have searched but couldn't find a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `collection for` to build the DataColumn list.

```dart
final columnTitles = widget.titles.split('~');
final columnTypes = widget.columnTypes.split('~');

final dataColumns = [
  for (var i = 0; i < columnTitles.length; i++)
    DataColumn(
      label: Text(columnTitles[i]),
      numeric: columnTypes[i] == 'N',
    ),
];
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the quick response. Just one small mistake that you may like to remove. "final" may be replaced with "int", so that its value could be changed thru iteration.

Comment: ah. that's true. I am too used to `for (final thing in things)` syntax. I will update the answer. Thanks!